# React-native gives 'native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, when creating new project

Tags: react-native, gradle

Hi I made a few app with react-native.They works fine without error.I run my applications with this command

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Today I tryed to create new app with this command

```
react-native init myNewProject
```

It installed libraries etc. I opened it with vs code and run this command

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

Then it opends the avd device and gives this error. But my old projects works fine. Whats the problem.
Thank you.

The project[image]
Error
[image]
'native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Also
[image]

I installed this, it took a time

```
choco install -y nodejs.install openjdk8
```

Then I created project in react-native docs

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

But it still same

```
AwesomeProject> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
'native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Comment: can you try running npx react-native run-android instead? I'm not sure, but maybe it is something to do with react-native cli.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup  in the session "React Native Command Line Interface" they recommend to use npx that it's built in in npm

Comment: It still same whyy

Comment: Can anybody help